# отправка и получение СМС с помощью AT комманд на С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, usb, модемы, at

пишу программу для отправки смс и получения ответов от удаленных клиентов.
собственно с отправкой СМС уже рабобрался, хотя и не просто это как пишут в интернете.
есть несколько вопросов по поведению модема, и почему он ведет себя не так, как от него ожидается. Аесли точнее, то как получить СМС на модеме.
при переводе модема в текстовый режим коммандой

```
AT+CMGF=1
```

через некоторое непродолжительное время( секунд 5) его ответ меняется без действий с моей стороны.

```
Send:AT+CMGF?

Recieve: +CMGF: 1
Recieve: OK

Send:AT+CMGF?

Recieve: +CMGF: 0
Recieve: OK
```

то есть он сам по себе поменял режим работы в числовой.
это не проблема т.к. я отправляю СМС в числовом режиме.
однако при отправке команды проверки памяти СМС

```
AT+CPMS?
```

я по лучаю разные ответы:

```
Send:AT+CPMS?

Recieve: +CPMS: "SR",0,0,"SM",0,20,"SR",0,0
Recieve: OK

Send:AT+CPMS?

Recieve: +CPMS: "SM",0,20,"SM",0,20,"SR",0,0
Recieve: OK

Send:AT+CPMS?

Recieve: +CPMS: "SR",0,0,"SM",0,20,"SR",0,0
Recieve: OK
```

а на комманду

```
AT+CMGL=4
```

ответ всегда один

```
Send:AT+CMGL=4

Recieve: OK
```

хотя ответ должен содержать текста всех полученных СМС.
для того, что бы поймать входющую СМС, я сделал небольшую программу для отправки AT комманд и зациклил ее для получения ответа
вот что получилось:

```
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "ME",0,23,"MT",0,23,"SM",0,20OK^RSSI:20
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "SR",0,0,"MT",0,23,"SM",1,20OK
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK^RSSI:20
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "SR",0,0,"MT",0,23,"SM",1,20OK
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "SR",0,0,"MT",0,23,"SM",1,20OK^RSSI:20
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "SR",0,0,"MT",0,23,"SM",1,20OK
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK^RSSI:20
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "SR",0,0,"MT",0,23,"SM",1,20OK
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "SR",0,0,"MT",0,23,"SM",1,20OK^RSSI:20
send:AT+CMGL=4
recieve:OK
send:AT+CPMS?
recieve:+CPMS: "SM",0,20,"MT",0,23,"SM",0,20OK
```

в ответе много переходов на новую строку, поэтому я их удалил. и OK припечатываются на одной строке.
0.5сек на отпраку комманды и еще 0.5 на получение ответа. то есть цикл программы из отправки 2-х комманд- 2 секунды.
в памяти видно некоторое время одну СМС( это я с телефона на него отправил СМС), но он ее не показывает и удаляет.

собственно вопрос: как мне прочитать полученную СМС?

код программы:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Этот файл содержит функцию "main". Здесь начинается и заканчивается выполнение программы.
//

#include "pch.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h> 
//#include <Winbase.h>
#define PAUSE 500
#define BUFSIZE 4096

//преобразовывает в нужный формат для открытия порта.
wchar_t *convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
{
    wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
}

//функция преобразования числа в строку
//пробегает по всем разрядам в пределах i разрядов
//возвращает истину, если число было(>0) ложь- 0 или разрядов в нем больше, чем i
bool int_to_char(const int a, char*b,const int i)
{
    int q = 0;
    int q0 = 0;//текущая позиция в строке
    int q1 = 1; //для указания на нужный разряд
    for (q = 0; q < i; q++) q1 *= 10;
    //буфер для значения
    int q2 = 0;
    //флаг ИСТИНА когда начали появляться символы в разряде
    bool flag=FALSE;
    for (q = 0; q < i; q++)
    {
        q1 /= 10;
        if (q2 = (a / q1) % 10)
        {
            flag = TRUE;
            b[q0] = q2 + 48;
        }
        if (flag) q0++;
    }
    //добавление символа конца строки
    b[q0] = 0;
    return flag;
}

int mysize(const char* in)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (in[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

//убирает символы \r \n из строки если достигнет максимальной длинны строки( max) возвращает 1. in - входная строка. будет изменена
int rncleaner(char*in, int max)
{
    int err = 0;
    //bool flag=FALSE;
    int i = 0, i1 = 0;
    for (; in[i]; i++)
    {
        if (i == max)
        {
            err = 1;
            break;
        }
        if (in[i] == '\n')
            continue;
        if (in[i] == '\r')
            continue;
        if (i != i1)
            in[i1] = in[i];
        i1++;
    }
    in[i1] = in[i];
    return err;
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //bool flag = TRUE;
    int i = 0,i1=0;
    DWORD  dwBytesRead, dwBytesWritten=0, dwBufSize = BUFSIZE;
    //char szTempName[MAX_PATH];
    char buffer[BUFSIZE],vbuffer[BUFSIZE];
    //char lpPathBuffer[BUFSIZE];

    int ERR = 0;
    //сюда вставлять сообщение
    char *smsmsg[9];
    /*
    0   AT+CMGF=0\r\nAT+CMGS=
    1   длинна сообщения
    2   \r\n
    3   0011000B91
    4   преобразованный номер
    5   0008C146
    6   сообщение
    7   символ ctrl+z 1a
    */
    smsmsg[0] = new char[30];
    strcpy_s(smsmsg[0],30, "AT+CMGF=0\r\n\0");
    smsmsg[1] = new char[30];
    strcpy_s(smsmsg[1], 30, "AT+CMGS=\0");
    smsmsg[2] = new char[4];
    smsmsg[2][0] = 0; smsmsg[2][1] = 0; smsmsg[2][2] = 0; smsmsg[2][3] = 0;
    int_to_char(7 + 4, smsmsg[2], 3);
    smsmsg[3] = new char[3];
    strcpy_s(smsmsg[3],3, "\r\n\0");
    smsmsg[4] = new char[11];
    strcpy_s(smsmsg[4],11, "0011000B91\0");
    smsmsg[5] = new char[13];
    //79535990019F
    strcpy_s(smsmsg[5], 13, "9735959999F9\0");
    smsmsg[6] = new char[9];
    strcpy_s(smsmsg[6],9, "0008C146\0");
    smsmsg[7] = new char[500];
    smsmsg[7][0] = 0;
    strcpy_s(smsmsg[7], 500, "0074006500730074\0");
    smsmsg[8] = new char[2];
    smsmsg[8][0] = 0x1a; smsmsg[8][1] = 0;
    //smsmsg[1]-запичать количество символов в сообщении. 7+
    //smsmsg[6]-записать сообщение
    //объявление порта
    HANDLE hSerial;
    //имя порта в удобном для изменения виде
    char port_name[10] = "\\\\.\\COM13";
    //имя в нужном программе, формате
    LPCTSTR sPortName = convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(port_name);
    //проверка конфигурации порта
    COMMCONFIG  comm;

    //для теста 

    //std::cout << "mysize : " << smsmsg[0] <<endl<<"is:"<< mysize(smsmsg[0])<<endl;





    if (GetDefaultCommConfig(sPortName, &comm, &comm.dwSize))
    {
        switch (comm.dwProviderSubType)
        {
        case  PST_FAX:
            cout << "FAX device " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_LAT:
            cout << "LAT protocol" << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_MODEM:
            cout << "Modem device " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_NETWORK_BRIDGE:
            cout << "Unspecified network bridge " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_PARALLELPORT:
            cout << "Parallel port " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_RS232:
            cout << "RS-232 serial port " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_RS422:
            cout << "RS-422 port " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_RS423:
            cout << "RS-423 port " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_RS449:
            cout << "RS-449 port " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_SCANNER:
            cout << "Scanner device " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_TCPIP_TELNET:
            cout << "TCP/IP TelnetR protocol " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_UNSPECIFIED:
            cout << "Unspecified " << endl;
            break;
        case  PST_X25:
            cout << "X.25 standards " << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "?????? Microsft mail please  ...." << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    else cout << "Error access" << endl;


    hSerial = ::CreateFile(sPortName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,0, NULL);

    //std::cout << "port: " << port_name << endl;

    //проверка на открытие порта
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            std::cout << "serial port does not exist.\n";
        }
        std::cout << "some other error occurred.\n"<< "error code: " << (int)GetLastError() << endl;

        std::cin.get();
        ERR= (int)GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "port "<< port_name <<" has been opend\n";
        //std::cout << _tcslen(sPortName)<<'\n';
        buffer[0] = 0;
    //  ReadFile(hSerial, buffer, dwBufSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    //  Sleep(PAUSE);
    //  buffer[dwBytesRead] = 0;
    //  rncleaner(buffer, dwBufSize);
    //  cout << "recieve:"<< buffer << endl;

        //первая комманда, которая устанавливает режим работы модема.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        buffer[0] = 0;
        strcpy_s(buffer, 30, "AT+CMGL=4\r\n\0");

        WriteFile(hSerial, buffer, mysize(buffer)+1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        rncleaner(buffer, dwBufSize);
        cout << "send:" << buffer << endl;
        Sleep(PAUSE);

        buffer[0] = 0;
        ReadFile(hSerial, buffer, dwBufSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
        Sleep(PAUSE);
        buffer[dwBytesRead] = 0;
        rncleaner(buffer, dwBufSize);
        cout << "recieve:" << buffer << endl;


        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) 
        {

            buffer[0] = 0;
            strcpy_s(buffer, 30, "AT+CPMS?\r\n\0");
            WriteFile(hSerial, buffer, mysize(buffer) + 1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
            Sleep(PAUSE);
            rncleaner(buffer, dwBufSize);
            cout << "send:" << buffer << endl;


            buffer[0] = 0;
            ReadFile(hSerial, buffer, dwBufSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
            Sleep(PAUSE);
            buffer[dwBytesRead] = 0;
            rncleaner(buffer, dwBufSize);
            cout << "recieve:" << buffer << endl;

            buffer[0] = 0;
            strcpy_s(buffer, 30, "AT+CMGL=4\r\n\0");
            WriteFile(hSerial, buffer, mysize(buffer) + 1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
            Sleep(PAUSE);
            rncleaner(buffer, dwBufSize);
            cout << "send:" << buffer << endl;


            buffer[0] = 0;
            ReadFile(hSerial, buffer, dwBufSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
            Sleep(PAUSE);
            buffer[dwBytesRead] = 0;
            rncleaner(buffer, dwBufSize);
            cout << "recieve:" << buffer << endl;
        }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*
    //вторая, в ней содержится комманда на передачу и длинна сообщения
    buffer[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        strncat_s(buffer, smsmsg[i], 2000);
    }
    //std::cout << "message has:"<< sizeof(buffer)<<endl<<"is :\n" << buffer<< endl;
    WriteFile(hSerial, buffer, mysize(buffer) + 1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    //std::cout << "written bytes:" << dwBytesWritten << endl;
    Sleep(PAUSE);
    //третья содержит сообщение. сообщение заканчивается символом ctrl+z.
    buffer[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i < 9; i++)
    {
        strncat_s(buffer, smsmsg[i], 2000);
    }
    //std::cout << "message has:"<< sizeof(buffer)<<endl<<"is :\n" << buffer<< endl;
    WriteFile(hSerial, buffer, mysize(buffer) + 1, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    //std::cout << "written bytes:" << dwBytesWritten << endl;
    */

        //ReadFile(COMport, bufrd, btr, &temp, &overlapped);
    }
    //закрытие порта, если он открыт
    if (hSerial != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        std::cout << "port " << port_name << " closed.\n";
    }
    delete[]smsmsg[0];
    delete[]smsmsg[1];
    delete[]smsmsg[2];
    delete[]smsmsg[3];
    delete[]smsmsg[4];
    delete[]smsmsg[5];
    delete[]smsmsg[6];
    delete[]smsmsg[7];
    delete[]smsmsg[8];

    std::cin.get();
    return ERR;

}
```

Comment: А как вы применяете программу? Телефон по usb подключен или как? Где об этом почитать? Как все соединено, что программа видит команды?

Comment: к компьютеру подключен USB модем Huawei e173. по диспетчеру устройст он на 13 ком порту. туда же можно подключиться программами  "my huawei terminal" или Putty. они получают теже ответы, что и моя программа. в программе просто можно зациклить и заставить отправлять комманды довольно быстро. добавил код программы в заголовок

Comment: Посмотри не зашел ли ещё кто на порт. Драйвера хуавея или виндовс могут портить кнофиг с другого порта

Comment: с проблемой сброса конфига и удалением сообщений я справился удалив программу СМС сервера( думал использовать стороннюю программу, но потом отказался в пользу своего велосипеда с блек джеком и барышнями). COM порт приватизируется при подключении, но сторонняя программа видимо через другой порт с ним соединилась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

спустя не долгое время, я понял, что программа для получения и отправки SMS постоянно меняла режим работы модема и удаляла СМС.

итак. теперь у меня СМС не пропадали. узнать о приходящей СМС можно проверив память:

```
Send:AT+CPMS="SM"

Recieve: +CPMS: 1,20,1,20,1,20
Recieve: OK
```

а вот следующая команда у меня работала не так как ожидается и от неё решено отказаться:

```
AT+CMGL=4
```

и тут я начал экспериментировать с другой командой:

```
AT+CMGR=0

Recieve: +CMGR: 1,,21
Recieve: 07919761980644F0040B919735999999F900009110601154052102C633
Recieve: OK
```

индекс входящих сообщений начинается с 0. а СМС "Fg" собственно в последних 2-х байтах. 7 битная кодировка мне не приятна и сложна для работы, поэтому я перейду к 16 битной UCS-2:

```
Send:AT+CSCS="UCS2"
```

подробней о AT командах: https://www.developershome.com/sms/smsIntro.asp